# Effectively storing arrays of float and short values in a file

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am currently in the planning stage of an *Android application* in which I will need to read some values stored in files. The values will be floats of an unknown (but potentially large) amount that in the application will be put into `FloatBuffer`s when loaded.
The float values will come in groups of five and in groups of three.

I do not have that much experience when it comes to efficient file writing (or reading) but my idea is to create the files using a [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html), to write the floats, preceded with a length-index describing the amount of five-groups. After that amount the three-groups can be written.
*As I am writing this I have also found the [`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) which could help with reading directly into the buffers, but I have never used this before and is a bit uncertain on how to use it in this case.*

Now, before I actually write any code I would like to get some input on this. Will it be effective using this (I am specifically thinking about the reading from file into buffer), or is there a better way to go about it?
I will include some specifications for the file below:

**The file will have to be able to:**

- Contain groups of five floats.
- Contain groups of three floats. (Both in the same file)
- Be ordered. The order of the groups is very important, as well as the order of the values in the groups.
- Allow for efficient (fast and not too memory consuming) reading into FloatBuffer.

**The file will not have to be:**

- Modifiable. The application will only read the data from the files, they will never be modified after having been.
- Secure. The data in the files will never represent anything such as passwords or other sensitive data.
- Fast to write. The creation of the file will be done beforehand, on a computer. In the mobile application it will be read-only.

Thank you for your responses.

**Edit**: after some quick and dirty testing, I have compared the performance of the RandomAccessFile and a buffered DataInputStream for reading the data. The results show that DataInputStream is much faster (10-100%, depending on the amount of files).

Comment: You can also use a `Scanner` to read from the file -- or a `RandomAccessFile`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement all these yourself but I'd recommend you to think about database. Andoroid supports SQLite, so take it and use. Create 2 tables: `GROUP5` and 'GROUP53`. Define relevant indexes and you will be able to store data, retrieve it using any sorting policy etc.

If you still prefer to make your own implementation I'd recommend you to store data in 2 files: one for 5 fields and other for 3 fields. In this case you will always know the data record size, so you will be able to use random access (either using `RandomAccessFile` or by using `mark()` and `skip()` for regular `FileInputStream`.

Using of file channel does not have any advantages here. It allows reading from several files simultaneously. Reading from one file just cause performance degradation relatively to regular `FileInputStream` (http://alexradzin.blogspot.com/2011/07/file-access-stream-vs-nio-channel.html).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, using a database seems like an option, but for now I would like to create a custom implementation.
I will look into the RandomAccessFile and see if this might be what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of Data is huge I would still go with a SQLite Database. With the Helper it is easy to handle huge amounts of Data and as far as I know due to its efficient handling of queries it is fast for random access of data sets (If you want to sequentially read your file then it is probably not faster than  the Dataoutputstream, because then the query routine of SQL will always query the database and process the result cursor instead of just increasing the position counter in your file by x). I am not sure if it is the fastest way but it is definitely a convenient and fast way.